# input type range - output on thumb error

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suddenly my code stopped working, the problem is that i want to output the range value to the thumb of the range.

Here's my code:

```
 <input id="slider1" type="range" min="5000" max="350000" step="1000" value="5000" name="beloeb" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" />
```

Js:

```
 function outputUpdate(vol) {
function formatNumber (num) {
return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
}
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb::before','content: "'+formatNumber(vol)+' DKK";');
}
```

This is the error when using chrome in console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule '#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb::before { content: "8.000 DKK"; }'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::-webkit-slider-thumb` is [not a standard pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-thumb)

***This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.***

If you check your code in CSS Validator you will have something like:

`::-webkit-slider-thumb is an unknown vendor extended pseudo-element`

So probably a newer version of the browser stops supporting the property.

There is not a standard way to achieve that with CSS right now. But there are some nice tools that implement the same result using divs/spans like http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Comment: Is there any other way to add the value to the range thumb?

Comment: @PatrickLarsen I dont see any standard cross-browser supported way to do it easily. You can check this article https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/ but is not a well supported feature.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [Avraam's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36580714/557445), the `::webkit-slider-thumb` style is non-standard and will not work in any kind of cross-browser sense. As a result the `styleSheet.addRule()` function will be unable to parse it.

You could consider using Javascript to create a `<style>` block that contained the style you are targeting if one doesn't already exist in the current page as opposed to adding it directly to the stylesheet :

```
<script>
  function outputUpdate(vol) {
    // Create a style block
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    // Set an ID for style and type
    style.id = 'slider-rule';
    style.type = 'text/css';
    // If the style doesn't exist in the DOM...
    if(!document.getElementById(style.id)){
      // Resolve the head section of the document
      var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      // Style content
      var content = '#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb::before{ content: "'+formatNumber(vol)+' DKK";}';
      if (style.styleSheet){
          style.styleSheet.cssText = content;
      } else {
          style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
      }
      // Append this tag to the <head> section
      head.appendChild(style);
    }
  }

  function formatNumber (num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
  }
</script>
```

This obviously doesn't resolve the cross-browser concerns, but it will add the proper `<style>` block to the DOM if it doesn't exist :

[image]